# Google Sheets - After Cell A37 is populated, need to auto jump to cell E9

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Once cell A37 (bottom of my 1st input column) is populated, I need to automatically jump to cell E9 (top of my next input column).

Here's my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18zCSr2nkdQaqRU2FiX7hClRirsTt4NG5yElRJh3xKz8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## After Cell A37 is populated jump to cell E9

```
   function onEdit(e) {
      if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==37) {
        e.range.getSheet().getRange('E9').activate();
      }
    }
```